# automate install using autoit remotely

Tags: automation, installation, autoit

I am wondering if I can use autoit to install a package that doesn't have a silent switch to a remote computer. I have the script and it runs the installer on the remote server but it hangs. I have a guess that because I am running the autoit script remotely, it doesn't work because GUI is not provided.

Comment: Can you run the AutoIt script on the remote server as well?

Comment: Oh I am running the compiled .exe not the .au3

Comment: Are you running the executable on the remote server then? (they are the same thing from AutoIt's point of view)

Comment: Yeah I am copying the .exe file and running it from the server. Do I have to install autoit on the server for it to run properly?

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. I was just wondering whether the AutoIt program was running the installation remotely, or whether you were remotely running the AutoIt program to run the installer (if that makes any sense at all).

Comment: yeah the autoit script is running the installer

Comment: But do you execute it via a remote command? Which means, the executable would exist on the remote file system, but the execution is on your local device. Or do you somehow login into the remote computer and start the executable locally on the remote system? Do you get the question?

Comment: I am using powershell to create a batch file and execute the batch file that runs the autoit script

Answer (score 1):

You could use `FileInstall(...)` to include the program's installer in a compiled autoit script and include your automation that way:

```
;SCRIPTEDINSTALL.AU3
FileInstall("C:\REMOTEINSTALL\INCLUDES\INSTALL.EXE",@TEMPDIR & "\INSTALL.EXE")

; AutoMagical Installation Techniques Here
```

Then,

```
Invoke SCRIPTEDINSTALL.EXE on REMOTE from LOCAL
```

If you are trying this:

```
Run AutoIt Script (SCRIPT.EXE) on LOCAL
Invoke Remote Installation (INSTALL.EXE) on REMOTE from LOCAL
```

And trying to have SCRIPT.EXE pick up details from INSTALL.EXE, then no, this will not work (through any methods I know of).  Sorry =(

Lastly, if you mean to ask "do I need to install AutoIt on a remote server to run an AutoIt Script?" Then:
Yes, if you don't compile it to EXE.
If you compile the script, though, it will run on any Windows computer.